# Navbar not working on certain pages, very weird

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap 4 collapsible navbar that works on the index page and another page, now when I go to another page that is not one of those two the collapsible navbar does not seem to work. Even though it is all copy-paste from the index page.

I have tried different version of bootstrap 4 and tried using one of the default navbars from bootstrap but those did not seem to work either.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar bg-custom navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index"><img src="dist/img/logo_yme.png" alt="Logo" width="236"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item animated"><a class="nav-link" href="vacatures">Vacatures</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item animated"><a class="nav-link" href="fotos">foto's</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item animated"><a class="nav-link" href="contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Links in the head tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/css/main.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Didact+Gothic&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

When the menu is collapsed I expect it to work, but this is not the case.
I am not getting any error messages in the console or anything.
When looking at the Network tab everything is loading in fine.

**NOTE: I have some custom routing in my .htaccess file which makes it so it does not need the extension behind it.**

**code in .htaccess:**

```
# mod_rewrite starts here

RewriteEngine on

# does not apply to existing directories, meaning that if the folder exists on the server then don't change anything and don't run the rule!!!!!

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Check for files with .html extension

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f

# Here we show the page that has the .html extension

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rookie mistake:**
I forgot to add the js files -,-